# Clarification about basics of size and resolution of images android

Tags: android-layout, android-imageview, android, android-image

I am developing Application for Tablets and Mobiles. My Application have an activity for Main menu with 4 Grid View images.I am not clear about size of the image,i want to design to fit all screens. I studied about dp,4 categories of resolution(ldpi,mdpi,hdpi,Xhdpi).But still i have following doubts,

- What actual size and resolution of image I want to design for four categories(ldpi,mdpi,hdpi,Xhdpi)?
- Shall i want to design a maximum size of image,and modify to 3:4:6:8 scaling ratio?Then what is the general size?
- If i put these 4 categories of size image,is it fit to all screen properly including mobile?
- If it fits to all screen,any problem occur in image quality?
- How to find a device it comes under which android resolution category?
- If i want to display 4 images on whole activity using Grid view in landscape mode, what size of image i want to design?

Comment: Pretty much all of these questions are impossible to answer, because it is entirely dependent on the desired appearance and the device on which it's running. A 10" tablet has much more screen real estate than a QVGA HTC Wildfire, and you should design your application to cope with that. This isn't iOS.

Comment: Then why Android said Support Multiple Screens.SO Android said,only for different resolutions not for different sizes?

Answer (score 1):

Here are some suggestions

> What actual size and resolution of image I want to design for four categories(ldpi,mdpi,hdpi,Xhdpi)?

1.I would suggest you test images on different devices .Let me know if there any other way also

> Shall i want to design a maximum size of image,and modify to 3:4:6:8 scaling ratio?Then what is the general size?

2.I dont have any idea about this

> If i put these 4 categories of size image,is it fit to all screen properly including mobile?

3.Again you need to test to ensure check all these.

> If it fits to all screen,any problem occur in image quality?

4.Suppose you put all your images in drawable-ldpi ,then images will pixelate in a tab.The correct approach is to put all respective images in drwable ldpi,mdpi,hdpi and xhdpi.But it is not a optimised way as this images make the app bulky.

> How to find a device it comes under which android resolution category?

5. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015094/determine-device-screen-category-small-normal-large-xlarge-using-code) this may answer your question

> If i want to display 4 images on whole activity using Grid view in landscape mode, what size of image i want to design?

6.To determine the actual size of image that is appropriate for your device  ,the only way to to test images with different sizes on each device.

Useful links

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6575875/android-multiple-screen-support)

[Multiple support screen](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#overview)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Please let me knowi f you find any solution for image size

Answer (score 0):

For this you have to create new folder in layout

> in that folder create different xml files for different screen sizes

- for differnt screens create diffrent images